# adding date detection into existing index + existing mapping

Tags: elasticsearch

I had created the following mapping for my `PRODUCT` index where I had activated the numeric detection on it.

```
{
  "product": {
    "mappings": {
      "numeric_detection": true,
      "properties": {
        "my_float": {
          "type": "float"
        },
        "my_integer": {
          "type": "long"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}  <br><Br>
```

When I would like to enable the date detection on the same index, I am getting the following error

```
{
  "error": "Incorrect HTTP method for uri [/product?pretty=true] and method [POST], allowed: [PUT, DELETE, GET, HEAD]",
  "status": 405
}<br><br>
```

The following are the elastic command that I am using for enable the date detection

```
post product
{
  "mappings":
  {
    "dynamic_date_fromats":
    [
      "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",
      "yyyy-MM-dd",
      "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss",
      "yyyy/MM/dd"
    ],
     "date_detection":true
  }
}
```

I dont want to create a new index with new mapping which it will contain date detection and numeric detection. I just want to know whether it have any way to update it without we recreate everything again?  I knew that we can update the `properties` part if we have new field that we want  to add it but I am not sure on the numeric detection and date detection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL you're hitting is for creating a new index. If the index is already created and you just want to modify the mapping, you simply need to call the [PUT Mapping API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html) which will simply update the existing mapping parameters:

```
PUT product/_mapping
{
    "dynamic_date_formats":
    [
      "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",
      "yyyy-MM-dd",
      "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss",
      "yyyy/MM/dd"
    ],
     "date_detection":true
}
```

Note: The update mapping API doesn't allow to make any kind of changes to your existing mapping, only [some changes are allowed](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html#put-mapping-api-example)

Also worth noting is that `date_detection` is enabled by default. The default supported date formats are `[ "strict_date_optional_time","yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss Z||yyyy/MM/dd Z"]`.